# jQuery: replace text inside element using .replace()

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to perform a "find and replace" operation on the text of certain elements stored in a jQuery object.  I want to replace the text using the javascript function `.replace()`, which uses a regex selector.  How to I correct this sample code?

```
$(JQUERY_OBJECT).html(
    $(this).text().replace(/REGEX_EXPRESSION/, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT')
);
```

*Note*: The jQuery objects I am manipulating may contain child elements, but I do not want to preserve them.  That is why I am using `.text()`.  If it is possible to run the `.replace()` function without discarding inner elements, though, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Provided you are using a very recent version of jQuery, the `.html()` method accepts a function as an argument, the function receives the current content as an argument and the return value is used to replace the current contents.

So the code would be:

```
$(JQUERY_OBJECT).html(function(idx,oldHtml){
   //idx is the index of the current element in the JQUERY_OBJECT
   return oldHtml.replace(/REGEX_EXPRESSION/, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT')
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Using `.text()` it's the same story

```
$(JQUERY_OBJECT).text(function(idx,oldText){
   //idx is the index of the current element in the JQUERY_OBJECT
   return oldText.replace(/REGEX_EXPRESSION/, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT')
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2

Or to re-write what you have already got using a combination of .html and .text

```
$(JQUERY_OBJECT).html(function(idx,oldHtml){
   return $(this).text().replace(/REGEX_EXPRESSION/, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT')
});
```

Comment: 1. Could you provide a link to the jQuery docs explaining the input arguments you told me about.  I could not find an explanation of what you told me on the jQuery .html() doc page.

Comment: 2. I need to get the contents of the element using the .text() function, not .html().  Could you revise your answer accordingly?

Comment: 2. But you would like to preserve the children of the elements, Don't think you can do that with .text()

Comment: 1. The link is already in the answer, if you can't see it when the page is loaded, do a search in the browser for `.html( function(index, oldhtml) )` when you get to that page.

Comment: Edited my answer to include the use of `.text()` in 2 different ways

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = $(this).text().replace(/REGEX_EXPRESSION/, 'REPLACEMENT_TEXT');
$(this).text(text);
```

Or you could use replaceWith instead of the second text() if that's more appropriate?